# Open current Chrome Tab in Safari script doesn't work

Tags: shell, google-chrome, tabs, safari, applescript

I want to open my current Chrome URL in Safari. But I'm messing up the quotes in the script and get an error: `error "The file /$theURL does not exist." number 1`

Here's the script:

```
property theURL : ""
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set theURL to (get URL of (active tab) of window 1)
end tell

do shell script "open -a Safari '$theURL' "
```

Can someone point me to the *do shell part* has to be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
do shell script "open -a Safari " & quoted form of theURL
```